# Is it safe for unity 3d to access an online database through a web service?

Tags: database, web-services, unity-game-engine

I'm planning on creating a single player game using Unity 3D.  The game needs to download the user's profile (and other info) from  an online database, which are created through an ASP .NET backend system by the administrator. The game will also need to upload the user's achievements onto the online database.

However I have read on Stack Overflow, that accessing an online database directly from unity 3d creates a security issue....

Does the above also apply if unity3d (game) access the online database through a web service?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using direct database connections may indeed be a security issue. Unless you use some sort of encryption, your access credentials can easily be accessed. I'd strongly opt for the *Webservice* approach you proposed. This is potentially more work, since you have to design the protocoll or find a suitable, but this is surely an acceptable investment in the long term.